# KEEP backlight off + LCD on with cursor/keyboard input

Tags: power-management, brightness, backlight

I'm trying to keep my backlight off but the LCD on even though inputs are coming from the keyboard and/or trackpad.

I'm working on an Asus Aspire One running Linux Mint (32bit). 
I've just installed a Pixel Qi display that allows viewing in sunlight through a reflective display (think: epaper).

The Fn+F6 native shortcut effectively turns off the backlight, but any input reactivates the screen.

I've tried a few things already: 
• xbacklight only dims the screen, and even at 0 or neg' values won't turn the backlight OFF. 
• i've tried a handfull of commands that turn the screen off, but they either turn the LCD itself off requiring the inverse command, or they still get woken by any peripheral input. 
• I've tried "echo" to change the brightness value in the /sys.../backlight/brightness file but even with sudo or su- i get "access denied"

I have a sense this is more power management/sleep setting than backlight. Basically need to tell the computer NOT to turn the backlight back on with the inputs.

Comment: I've also tried toggling the mouse/keyboard wakeup per this thread:

Comment: http://www.das-werkstatt.com/forum/werkstatt/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1985

Comment: the above had no effect on keeping the backlight off